# 'He's in bed with José from the liquor store' -- does this line remain in the movie?

Tags: soundtrack, in-the-heights

I recall a line from the *In The Heights* musical:

> Yesenia walks in the room
> She smells sex and cheap perfume
> She screams, “Who's in there with you, Julio?”
> Grabs a bat and kicks in the door
> He's in bed with José from the liquor store!
>
> *No me diga* [You don't say!]
> [source](https://genius.com/Lin-manuel-miranda-and-in-the-heights-original-broadway-company-in-the-heights-lyrics)

Is this line in the movie? I haven't seen it yet.

Here the punchline is bisexuality (the setup suggests infidelity with a woman, pull back, and reveal infidelity with a man), so I anticipate the movie may have changed it, conscious of social justice
scrutiny.

https://filmdaze.net/the-b-word-the-erasure-of-bisexuality-in-cinema/ describes biphobic tropes:

> There’s a long-standing stereotype that bisexual people are more likely to cheat on their partners and are incapable of commitment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > .. She screams, “Who's in there with you, Julio?”
> >
> > Grabs a bat and kicks in the door,
> >
> > Hes in bed with José from the liquor store!
> > No me diga [You don't say!]

---

> Is this line in the movie? I haven't seen it yet.

### Yes, it is...completely as you remember it.

A comprehensive what are the differences (if any) between the movie and the show is too broad for further discussion.